# Finding the $\gcd$ of two polynomials over $\Bbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, unique-factorization-domains

I understand that there are other posts on the forum about the same topic, but, after reading them, I didn't understand exactly what to do in this situation.

**What I've done so far.** In this same exercise, I have already shown that $\Bbb Z[x]$ is an UFD (obvious, since $\Bbb Z$ is an UFD and using Gauss' Theorem) but not an euclidian domain (to do this, I considered the ideal $(2,x)$ and showed this isn't a principal ideal and thus $\Bbb Z[x]$ isn't a PID $\Rightarrow$ $\Bbb Z[x]$ is not an Euclidian domain). Besides from this, I was also asked to decompose the polynomial $1+x+x^2+x^3$ in irreducibles and I came up with the following conclusion:
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 = (1+x)(1+x^2)
\end{equation*}
which are both irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb Z[x]$. But after this, I am asked to compute the $\gcd$ between $f$ and $f'$ and I don't know how to proceed with $\gcd$ calculation over a **NOT** Euclidian domain, like $\Bbb Z$. Is my decomposition in irreducibles helpfull somehow?

**Example.** Altough there is no algorithm in $\Bbb Z[x]$ based on an euclidian evaluation to compute $\gcd$'s, compute the following:
\begin{equation*}
\gcd(1+x+x^2+x^3,1+2x+3x^2)
\end{equation*}

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: In a UFD, if $a=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$ and $b=p_1^{\beta_1}...p_k^{\beta_k}$ are the decomposition of two elements $a$ and $b$ in a product of irreducible elements, then one has $$\gcd(a,b)=p_1^{\min(\alpha_1,\beta_1)}...p_k^{\min(\alpha_k,\beta_k)}$$

Comment: We have $\gcd(1+x+x^2+x^3,1+2x+3x^2)=1$. In any UFD, any two elements have a $\gcd$, and $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a UFD.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understand that, but how would one **SHOW** that $1$ is the actual $\gcd$ ?

Comment: One would show this exactly as in the first comment **ABOVE**. Obviously $1+2x+3x^2$ is irreducible, i.e., has no non-constant factor by the rational root test, and $1+x+x^2+x^3=(1+x)(1+x^2)$ is the factorization into irreducible factors, as you said.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for your comments guys! Here is what I came up with your help. Can you check if it looks ok? First, we have the two following decompositions: \begin{equation*} f' = f' \times 1 \quad f = (1+x)(1+x^2) \end{equation*} ,where the first decomposition follows directly since $f'$ is irreducible. But this decompostions are equivalent to: \begin{equation*} f' = 1 \times f' (1+x)^{0}(1+x^2)^{0} \quad f = 1 \times f'^{0}(1+x)(1+x^2) \end{equation*} And so it follows directly that \begin{equation*} \gcd(f,f') = 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 = 1 \end{equation*} Does this look ok?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to approach the problem.

Let your polynomials be $P_1(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3$ and $P_2(x)=1+2x+3x^2$.  Any common factor of $P_1$ and $P_2$ will also be a common factor of any linear combination of $P_1$ and $P_2$ (linear combination with coefficients coming from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$). Also linear combinations of linear combinations of $P_1$ and $P_2$ will again be linear combinations of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

So any any common factor of $P_1$ and $P_2$ will also be a factor of $P_3=3P_1-xP_2=3+2x+x^2$.

Then any common factor of $P_1$ and $P_2$ will also be a factor of $P_4=3P_3-P_2=8+4x$.

But $P_4(x)$ has irreducible factors of $2$ and $2+x$, neither of which is a factor of $P_1$ (or of $P_2$ for that matter), so  $P_1$ and $P_2$ have no common factors other than $1$ (and $-1$).

Comment: I am not used to the term "common factor" since English is not my native language. Let's say $d$ is a common factor of $a$ and $b$. This means that $d$ divides $a$ and $d$ divides $b$ ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: One interpretation of this answer:  even though $\mathbb Z[x]$ isn't a Euclidean domain, you can still perform the Euclidean algorithm in the Euclidean domain $\mathbb Q[x]$, and keep everything in $\mathbb Z[x]$ by clearing the (integer) denominators.  This can be carried out until you reach a constant if you like.  Although that specific constant won't be a common divisor of the original polynomials (thanks to clearing denominators), it still follows that all common divisors are divisors of that constant.  You can then check directly whether the two polynomials have a common constant factor.